# How to remove '0x' in hex and get 2 digits

Tags: python-3.7

I am having a hex output `"Res"` which looks like this:

```
Res = 0x0 0x1a 0x9 0x14 0x13 0x0
```

I want to 
- remove the '0x' from the beginning of each 
-have 2 digits 
- and to remove the spaces in between

i.e I want to have the Res like this: `001a09141300`

I tried `.join` but then I want to have 2 digits first.

Comment: When its ```0x0``` you want 00 added to the string or a single 0. It's a little confusing.

Comment: I want at first : 00 1a  09  14  13  00 and then remove spaces in between 001a09141300

Comment: This ```Res``` variable is it a string? or an array?

Comment: it is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to approach it:

```
res='0x0 0x1a 0x9 0x14 0x13 0x0'
newStr=''
for x in res.split(' '):
    x=x[2:]
    if len(x)<2:
        x='0'+x
    newStr=newStr+x

print(newStr)
```

**Output:**

> 001a09141300

Comment: this one only adds a 0 to the left if it is a zero. I wanted a zero to the left everywhere where there is single ( e.g 0x9 -->09)

Comment: @matt Oh Sorry My Bad! Have modified the code accordingly. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```py
res = '0x0 0x1a 0x9 0x14 0x13 0x0'
li = [int(s, 16) for s in res.split()]   # [0, 26, 9, 20, 19, 0]
ls = [f"{i:0>2x}" for i in li]   # ['00', '1a', '09', '14', '13', '00']
result = "".join(ls)

print(result)   # 001a09141300
```

You need Python 3.6 or higher to use f-string.

If your Python version is lower than that, you may use `ls = ["{:0>2x}".format(i) for i in li]` instead.

Explanation of `f"{i:0>2x}"`:

`>2`: Right align with width 2

`0` on the left: Fill the empty space with 0

`x` on th right: Represent as hexadecimal form

Answer (score 0):

```
res='0x0 0x1a 0x9 0x14 0x13 0x0'
hex_ls=[x.replace('0x','0') if len(x)<4 else x.replace('0x','') for x in res.split(" ")]
print("".join(hex_ls))
```

The output is 001a09141300

Answer (score 0):

```
res ='0x0 0x1a 0x9 0x14 0x13 0x0'
res = res.replace('0x', '')
res = res.zfill(4)
```